# Is this bash argument substitution?

Tags: bash, find, read, process-substitution

While studying bash process substitution, I found this:

```
counter=0

while IFS= read -rN1 _; do
    ((counter++))
done < <(find /etc -printf ' ')

echo "$counter files"
```

If I understand correctly, the output of find command substitutes the "_".

However:

- Which mechanism is this?
- Additionally: what does `read -rN1` do?

Update:

Additional question: 
The process substitution is pointing to the "done" in the while loop. How does this work, i.e., why would the while loop take a substitution at that place. Is there any thing general I can read about?

Comment: See also the accepted answer in this link, [What does “< <(cmd args)” mean in the shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443085/what-does-cmd-args-mean-in-the-shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<(find /etc -printf ' ')` is called "process substitution". It will generate **one** character (an space `' '`) per each file. The output of `find /etc -printf ' '` is made available in a file (or something that appears as a file). The name of this file is expanded on the command line. The **additional** `<` performs the redirection for stdin from that file.

`read -rN1 _` reads from (the redirected) stdin into a variable called `_`, one character at a time, and count those characters (which each represent one file).

Here are the `read` arguments from `man bash`:

```
-r     Backslash  does not act as an escape character.  The backslash is considered
       to be part of the line.  In particular, a backslash-newline pair may not  be
       used as a line continuation.

-N nchars
       read returns after reading exactly nchars characters rather than waiting for
       a  complete  line  of  input,  unless  EOF is encountered or read times out.
       Delimiter characters encountered in the input are not treated specially  and
       do not cause read to return until nchars characters are read.
```

Comment: I'm afraid the phrasing above is somewhat fuzzy: "is then read from STDIN into the while loop" and "what the while loop is currently presenting". The loop forms a block or "compound command" whose stdin is redirected from the "process substitution", and `read` within the block is the only consumer.

Comment: @RudiC: Great point, thank you. I researched this and concluded that my understanding of how the loop worked was incorrect. Does my latest edit look accurate?

Comment: I tried an edit to get the phrasing right but adhering as close as possible to your original...

Comment: if you dont mind, I have one last question and ready to take your answer (let me put it in the main question as well). The process substitution is pointing to the "done" in the while loop. How does this work, i.e., why would the while loop take a substitution at that place. Is there any thing general I can read about?

Comment: @drdot The whole `while ... done` construct is practically *one* command, `< <(...)` just sends the output of `<(...)` as standard input to the loop. You could (although it's rather silly) also run `cat < <(find .tmp -printf '.')` to just show the output in the terminal.

Comment: Note that in Bash, the `_` [special parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters) gets overwritten after every command, so whatever it is that `read` reads, you won't be able to see it later. It's used just as a dummy variable here.